# How many 4-digits even numbers and their sum.

Tags: combinatorics

> $40$-years-old John only knows even digits. How many $4$-digits
>   numbers he can write down? Find the sum of this numbers.

**Attempt:**

John knows $5$ digits $(0,\ 2,\ 4,\ 6,\ 8)$. We have 4 different places to place them. Certainly there are no $4$-digits numbers that begin with $0$ (that is, we don't take into account, for instance, the number $0846$). So in our first place we can put only $4$ out of out $5$ even numbers. In the remaining places there is no condition imposed, so John can write down:

$$4\cdot5^3 = 500\ \text{numbers}$$

Now let find the sum of these numbers.

A $4$-digit number in the decimal numerical system can be written as:

$$\overline{abcd} = a\cdot 10^3 + b\cdot 10^2 + c\cdot 10^1 + d\cdot 10^0$$

Certainly we want to find the sum of our $500$ numbers so,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{500}\overline{abcd} = \sum_{k=1}^{500}a\cdot 10^3 + \sum_{k=1}^{500}b\cdot 10^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{500}c\cdot 10^1 + \sum_{k=1}^{500} d\cdot 10^0$$

And here I'm stuck. I have to make some conclusions about the coefficient on the RHS, but I don't know which. Does really matter the fact that he is $40$ years old?

Comment: $$\sum_{evens}^{}\overline{abcd} = \sum_{p=1}^{4}\left (2p\cdot 10^3 + \sum_{q=0}^{4}\left (2q\cdot 10^2 + \sum_{r=0}^{4}\left (2r\cdot 10^1 + \sum_{s=0}^{4} 2s\cdot 10^0\right )\right )\right )$$

Comment: You need to change the header. You aren't dealing with all even numbers, only **numbers with all digits even**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, there will be $500$ such numbers.

Except for the thousandth place, the average value of a digit will be $(0+2+4+6+8)/5 = 4,$ while that for the thousandth place will be $(2+4+6+8)/4 = 5$

Thus overall sum $= 500(5\cdot10^3 + 4\cdot10^2 +4\cdot10^1 + 4\cdot10^0) = 2,722,000$

Answer (score 1):

You have a good start and noticed that you can add each tens-place individually.  To continue, notice that if we try to add the units digits of each of the numbers:

$$\begin{array}{r}2000\\2002\\2004\\2006\\\vdots\\+8888\\\hline\end{array}$$

We may instead group them according to their last digit:

$$\left(\begin{array}{r}2000\\2010\\2020\\\vdots\\ +8880\\\end{array}\right)\text{all the 0's}\\ \left(\begin{array}{r}2002\\2012\\2022\\\vdots\\ +8882\end{array}\right)\text{all the 2's}\\\vdots~~~~~~~$$

How many times does $0$ appear as the last digit of one of the numbers?  How much then does $0$ contribute to the overall sum of the units digit column?

How many times does $2$ appear as the last digit of one of the numbers?  How much then does $2$ contribute to the overall sum of the units digit column?

etc...

What then is the total of the units digit column?

> Exactly one fifth of the numbers in the list end with $0$.  Similarly exactly one fifth of the numbers end with 2,4,6, and 8 respectively.  The total sum for the units column of the summation is then $100\cdot 0 + 100\cdot 2+\dots+100\cdot 8 = 2000$

Do so similarly for ten's digit, hundred's digit, and thousand's digit columns.